# WSO2 Custom mediator is not returning in proper xml format

Tags: apache-axis, wso2, wso2-esb

I am having a custom mediator in my wso2 proxy service which transforms incoming xml to another format, in turn its been forwarded to a jms queue by the proxy. But the xml is not in proper format. It is shown like this in console and queue:

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <soapenv:Body>
            <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:ws="http://isova.wipro.com/">


                <arg0>&lt;Prescription xmlns="http://hl7.org/fhir">&#xd;
                    &lt;identifier>&#xd;
                    &lt;id value="A0001"/>&#xd;
                    &lt;/identifier>&#xd;
                    &lt;status value="active"/>&#xd;
                    &lt;patient>&#xd;
                    &lt;type value="Patient"/>&#xd;
                    &lt;url value="Bhavani"/>&#xd;
                    &lt;/patient>&#xd;
                    &lt;prescriber>&#xd;
                    &lt;type value="Provider"/>&#xd;
                    &lt;url value="Dr.Mathews"/>&#xd;
                    &lt;/prescriber>&#xd;
                    &lt;medicine>&#xd;
                    &lt;identification>&#xd;
                    &lt;text value="Zintac"/>&#xd;
                    &lt;/identification>&#xd;
                    &lt;/medicine>&#xd;
                    &lt;/Prescription></arg0>
            </soapenv:Envelope>
        </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

My proxy service:

```
    <proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="risresult"
        transports="https,http,jms" statistics="disable" trace="disable"
        startOnLoad="true">
        <target>
            <inSequence>
                <property name="ContentType" value="text/plain" scope="default"
                    type="STRING" />
                <class name="com.test.guru.HL7RISPrescription" />
                <property name="RESPONSE" value="true" />
                <header name="To" action="remove" />
                <send>
                    <endpoint>
                        <address
                            uri="jms:/prescription?

    transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName
    =QueueConnectionFactory&amp;java.naming.
    factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.
    ActiveMQInitialContextFactory&amp;java.
    naming.provider.url=tcp://localhost:61616" />
                    </endpoint>
                </send>
            </inSequence>
            <outSequence>
                <drop />
            </outSequence>
            <faultSequence />
        </target>
        <parameter name="transport.jms.ContentType">
            <rules>
                <jmsProperty>contentType</jmsProperty>
                <default>application/xml</default>
            </rules>
        </parameter>
        <description></description>
    </proxy>
```

What could be the reason for this? Is the problem because of the axis2 element?

My mediator class has these last statements:

```
   OMFactory factoryOM   = OMAbstractFactory.getOMFactory();
   OMElement code      = factoryOM.createOMElement("arg0","","");
   code.setText(pdoc.toString());
   axis2Element.addChild(code);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the conifiguration it seems you are using in proxy's in sequence.

```
<property name="ContentType" value="text/plain" scope="default"
                    type="STRING" />
```

What is the reason to use that? Remove that and try.That should cause escaped XML to make it text/plain. Use log mediator before and after your class mediator and log it full to observe the message content which will be helpful for you if there are further issues too.

Comment: Thank you Shelan. I removed it and tried now, It doesnt help. Still it gives the same issue. Any other suggestion for me ?

Comment: Just noticed that in mediator you are using  code.setText(pdoc.toString()); Build an OMelement using that string (not set text) and then add as a child elements for arg0. You are setting that as a text not as xml elements.

Comment: refer this for conversion. http://www.keith-chapman.org/2008/10/axiom-how-to-crate-omelement-from.html

Comment: Shelan, It works Cool. I used code.addChild(OMObject); Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This should work perfectly..

public class GetLocationMockMediator extends AbstractMediator {

```
public boolean mediate(MessageContext context) {        
    StringBuilder xml = new StringBuilder("<result><field1>field1Value</field1></result>");

    InputStream xmlInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.toString().getBytes());
    try {
        context.getEnvelope().getBody().addChild(new StAXOMBuilder(xmlInputStream).getDocumentElement());
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        // ignore
    } 

    return true;
}
```

}